# how to check every thread is completed or not in multiple thread?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3

```
threads = []  
images.each do |image|  
threads << Thread.new do
     creating images 
     .........................
   end
end
threads.each(&:join)
```

so after completed image creation i want to go next. So how could i check every thread execution is completed.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The code you posted already does that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your next thing after `threads.each(&:join)`. Thread `join` makes your thread to process one by one so your last thread will complete there and start execution of main thread or calling thread. If you still want to check thread is alive or not then you can do as following:

```
  while threads.any?(&:alive?) do
    #do nothing
  end
```